# How to fetch all meta_key and meta_value using post_id wihout duplication of post meta using sql query

Tags: mysql

How to fetch all meta_key and meta_value using post_id wihout duplication of post meta using sql query.

This query is repeting the post meta each time .

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM wp_posts
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta
ON wp_posts.ID= wp_postmeta.post_id
where post_type='property'";
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to write a custom SQL for this. You can always leverage WP's get_post_custom() that returns array of all custom fields for a particular page or post.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_custom